# Modified Weibull Error - the function failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, fitdistrplus

I'm trying to estimate the Almalki and Yuan's modified Weibull distribution (NMW)  parameters, but I'm encountering the following error:

The value of the AIC is giving negative ONLY VERY NEGATIVE. Something is wrong. I know that in the literature the AIC may be negative, but I believe that some error in the estimation or the functions is happening. Can the bug be in the estimation, fitdist or something like that? Somebody help me?

ARTICLE

```
 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0951832012002396
```

Acumulative Function

```
  pnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama,theta, lambda)
{
  1 - exp(-alpha*(x^(theta))-beta*(x^(gama))*exp(lambda*x))
}
```

Density Function

```
       dnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
{
  (alpha * theta * (x^(theta - 1)) + beta*(((gama+lambda*x)*(x^(gama-1))*exp(lambda*x))*exp(-alpha*x^(theta)-beta*x^(gama)*exp(lambda*x)))) 
}
```

Harzard Function

```
   hnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
{
  alpha * theta * x^(theta - 1) + beta * (gama  + lambda * x) * 
    x^(gama - 1) * exp(lambda * x)
}
```

Survival Function

```
   snmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
{
  exp(-alpha*x^(theta)-beta*x^(gama)*exp(lambda*x))
}
```

Estimation

```
paramYuan = fitdist(data = dadosp, distr = 'nmw', start = c(0.05,5,1.25,5,0.05),lower = c(0, 0))
```

IMAGES

```
 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDxwC.png][1] Image
    [https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Cid.png][1] Image Estimation
    [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FScsM.png][3] Image Functions
```

Sample:

```
    dadosp = c(240.3,71.9,271.3, 186.3,241,253,287.4,138.3,206.9,176,270.4,73.3,118.9,203.1,139.7,31,269.6,140.2,205.1,133.2,107,354.6,277,27.6,186,260.9,350.4,242.6,292.5, 112.3,242.8,310.7,309.9,53.1,326.5,145.7,271.5, 117.5,264.7,243.9,182,136.7,103.8,188.3,236,419.8,338.6,357.7)
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0KwD.png][1] IMAGE

Comment: You should look at `curve(snmw(x,0.05,5,1,1,0.05))` and see if a lightbulb in your head goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a little testing with your effort at a density function.

```
dnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
   {
(alpha * theta * (x^(theta - 1)) + beta*(((gama+lambda*x)*(x^(gama-1))*exp(lambda*x))*
     exp(-alpha*x^(theta)-beta*x^(gama)*exp(lambda*x)))) 
    }
 curve(dnmw(x,4,.3,2.4,2,0.05))
```

[image]

I think we need to conclude that this is NOT a good density function since it's integral is clearly greater than 1. Also look at the documentation: http://uksacb.org/sites/default/files/webform/Research%20Paper1_A%20new%20modi%EF%AC%81ed%20Weibull%20distribution_0.pdf

So take the code and put it into an R-aware editor and see where the match to the rightmost paren might be:

```
dnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
{
(alpha * theta * (x^(theta - 1)) + beta*(((gama+lambda*x)*(x^(gama-1))*exp(lambda*x))*
#^
             exp(-alpha*x^(theta)-beta*x^(gama)*exp(lambda*x)))) 
#                                                              ^
}
```

It matched with the one to the extreme left! But that left-paren was supposed to be matching the one just to the right of `exp(lambda*x)` to fence off what I would call the normalization terms. So put a right paren in that spot and try to figure out where there is a missing paren elsewhere. .... After several corrections, we get:

```
dnmw = function(x, alpha, beta, gama, theta, lambda)
{
  (alpha*theta*(x^(theta - 1)) +beta*( (gama+lambda*x) * x^(gama-1)*
  exp(lambda*x) ))*exp(-alpha*x^(theta)-beta*x^(gama)*exp(lambda*x))
}
```

[image]

And now things look more sensible when examining a graphical test. But I also think you need to make sure your other distribution functions do not have similar errors.

Comment: I have a second problem. I'm trying the parameters of the dell, I've put a density function on which you're suggested. Debian is giving the following error "" the function failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100 "", it is worth remembering that I am using the values ​​of the parameters of the graph that you presented. How do I make a mistake? I'll add the error to the question.

Comment: I don't know the source of the more recent error. I suspect that the effort to fit a 5 parameter distribution to a relatively small number of points may not be statistically proper, or perhaps five parameters is just too many for any data set.  I thought I was being helpful by correcting your syntactic error. The revision now is capable of duplicating the curves that were presented in the reference I cited.

Comment: Okay, :'( Thank you anyway!